# Customer receiving two order emails in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, order-email

When a customer places an order, they are receiving order confirmation email twice. What is the issue with this? Please help.
I am using magento 2.3.3

Comment: Which payment method do you use for placing an order? If its a 3rd party maybe they send out also the order confirmation email.

Comment: I am getting on all basically. I tired with Cash on delivey, credit memo and bank transfer